# Render a JS generated image in Pdf

Tags: visualforce

I am using a JS library called barcode39 to create a barcode image. I already imported the JS library in the static resource and have included the JS in my visualforce page. The barcode is generating fine in the VF page. The problem is I need to render this page as a pdf. When I do that, the barcode image does not appear. I DO NOT want to use the image url from the website barcodeinc because its very unstable. I would like to use this JS library. Can you please let me know what I can do to modify the code below to make the barcode render in pdf as well? Thank you

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="LPP_PackingSlip" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false">  
 <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.BarcodeScript}"/>  
    <head>  
<body>          

        <apex:outputText rendered="{!hasPictureDays}">                

            <!--Header-->
            <br/>
            <div class="headerSlip">{!Opportunity.Account.Name}</div><br/>
            <div class="jobSlip">{!Opportunity.WPA__c}</div>
            <center><svg id="barcode"></svg></center>
            <br/><br/>  
</apex:outputText>    
</body>


    <script type ="text/javascript">
        JsBarcode("#barcode", "{!Opportunity.WPA__c}",{
            fontOptions: "both",
            font :  "OCRB",
            textAlign : "center",
            Textmargin : 5,
            fontSize : 12,
            width: 1,
            height: 50

 });



  </script>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Won't work like that. Visualforce rendering to PDF is done server-side (using a Java library called "Flying Saucer"). There's no browser, no "engine" that can run your JavaScript.

You can ask the user to save the page as PDF. If you need it to be fully automated... there are JS libraries for PDF generation like [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)? They have bit limited range of features but for basic documents... (do your own research, this is just an example). And watch out for support of non-English characters (Japanese/Chinese/Korean...) - then again, Visualforce PDF generation also struggles with these and only safe font is [Arial Unicode MS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm).

If you need sending an email template with PDF attachment even that library won't help. You'll probably have to look into generating the barcode as image, attaching it to the record maybe (as real File/Attachment?) and then calling the template.